# Particle displacement at a rarefaction or compression

Tags: waves

In a longitudinal wave, why is there zero particle displacement at a compression or rarefaction and maximum displacement at a point pi/2 from it? Shouldn't it be the other way round?

Answer (score 1):

Basically the reason is as follows.  Consider a particle sitting exactly at what will become either a compression or rarefaction maximum.  That particle stays where it is while the particles to either side are pushed towards (or away from) its position.  Conversely, a particle starting at the half-way point ( $\pi/2$ ) will move quite a lot.

Perhaps the confusion is that the density remains constant at $\pi/2$ but the actual particles have moved "through" that region as the rarefaction region loses particles and the compression region gains particles.

Comment: This is a good answer. A picture would help illustrate what you're saying quite a lot.

Comment: @DanielSank even with computer tools, I'm a terrible artist.  Maybe I should use a Slinky (that old extended-spring toy) to demonstrate compression and extension locations.